# Calling on an array key in the url

Tags: php, arrays, url

Hello everyone I'm having a bit of trouble with a project. I need to be able to take the key of an array and call on the key of 1  in www.blach.com/1 and i need to display all the value inside of that key. How would i go about doing this, I've been searching for some time now but so far everything I've tried hasn't work any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [boxId] => 917
        [contentId] => 72
        [sectionType] => hp_spl_contestants
        [contentTypeId] => 83
        [categoryId] => 0
        [countryId] => 5
        [data] => {"title":"Contestant No.1","button_txt":"Latest From","image":"2d4f8f52d49d1ab9930bc40157013a31.jpg","author":"Meenakshi Negi","url":"","date":"2012-10-04 18:16:30","badget":0,"badget_date":""}
        [insertDate] => 2012-10-05 21:05:57
        [sortorder] => 1
        [sitename] => bb6
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [boxId] => 918
        [contentId] => 63
        [sectionType] => hp_spl_contestants
        [contentTypeId] => 83
        [categoryId] => 0
        [countryId] => 5
        [data] => {"title":"Contestant No.2","button_txt":"Latest From","image":"37154a5322838f61fb60cc24c8b5fe04.jpg","author":"Meenakshi Negi","url":"","date":"2012-10-04 18:09:06","badget":0,"badget_date":""}
        [insertDate] => 2012-10-05 21:06:16
        [sortorder] => 2
        [sitename] => bb6
    )
```

And I've tried

```
$obj = json_decode($ApiData);
$Array = json_decode(json_encode($obj), true);
$data = $Array;
$id = $_GET['id'];
foreach ($data[$id] as $key=>$value){
    echo "$key -> $value<br>";
}
    ?>
```

but it returns the following errors

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

When removing [$id] in the foreach and just passing in the array it returns this

```
0 -> Array
1 -> Array
2 -> Array
3 -> Array
4 -> Array
5 -> Array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ handler.php?id=$1
```

handler.php

```
<?php
$data = Array();
//here you load $data with whatever you want.
$id = $_GET['id'];
foreach ($data[$id] as $key=>$value){
    echo "$key -> $value<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was 100% clear I would like so when i have blah.com/id=1 that it displays all of the values inside of that array key.

Comment: @Charles this answer from @Nelson is 100% about your goal. it takes id (`$id = $_GET['id'];`) from the url user sent (ex= `blah.com/?id=1`) and takes from  array by this key `$data[$id]` and outputs all elements of that branch `echo "$key -> $value<br>";` the only thing you need is put your data in `$data` variable

Comment: But when I add the Array that is passed it give me and error of  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Other articles are saying that this happens if this isnt an array but i am passing an array into it and still reviving this error and have done var_dump to verify that is without any question that is  an array

Comment: Do print_r($data) just before "foreach" statement to check why your array is not right.

Comment: I've found the problem but not the solution                                                          '$id = $_GET['id'];
foreach ($data[$id]' and [$id is causing an error because when removed it works]

Comment: What's the url you are requesting?

Comment: You should print $id value. Is your php called handler.php? Did you correctly replace your .htaccess file?

Comment: The URL is blahblach.com\?Id=5  and yes I've double checks to make sure everything is places correctly

Comment: If your htaccess is working your url must be: blahblach.com/5

Comment: Yes but every time I return it to its original code I get invalid argument supplied in foreach it might become I use a lazy one liner and turned an STD obj array to a multi array

Comment: Print $id value and you will know why you are getting that error msg.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use the get method to call for the url, the 1 in your url have some value like number, then you can do, `$url = $_GET['number'];`and then you can use `$url` as an array key.

Comment: This is not what he wants. Just a little part of it.